# Phonegap iOS Command line tools ./create

Tags: cordova, command-line-tool, cordova-2.0.0

I want to create a iOS app using phonegap. My issue is that `./create <project_folder_path> <bundle_id> <project_name>` is not working at all. `./create ~/Desktop/projects/mbs/mastercard-iphone do.com.mbs.mastercard-iphone Mastercard`
 is returning info that can't copy the required files because the directory doesn't exist. Gist for actual errors. https://gist.github.com/3398261 Sounds like a users permission issue? should i run that command as sudo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure what the issue was, but I created the directory manually and then ran the ./create and everything worked.